# c++ virtual function confusion

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-functions

I am learning about virtual functions and i am very confused with the results of the below program
I was hoping that both `a1.virFun(b1)` and `b1.virFun(b1)` should return "hello from B", but the program returns "hello from A". This is contrary to my understanding. Can you please explain why `b1.sayHello()` is not being invoked, even when i am passing b1 as argument and `b1.sayHello()` is virtual function.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
 public:
 virtual void sayHello();
 void virFun(A obj);

 };

class B : public A
{
 public:
 void virFun(A obj);
 virtual void sayHello();

};

void A::sayHello()
 {
   cout << "hello from A" << endl;
 }

 void B::sayHello()
 {
   cout <<"hello from B" << endl;
 }

 void A::virFun(A obj)
 {
    obj.sayHello();
 }

 void B::virFun(A obj)
{
    obj.sayHello();
}

int main()
{
 A a1;
 B b1;

a1.virFun(b1);
b1.virFun(b1);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't passing `b1` as an argument, you are passing a copy of `b1` because you are passing by value. `b1` is a `B` and the argument *must be* the value of an `A` because that's what the function specification says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make virFun take a reference, not an A object by value:

```
 void A::virFun(A& obj) { obj.sayHello(); }
```

> *Reason*: If you take an `A` by value, the parameter will be initialized by making a copy of the value passed. If you pass a B, it will copy the 'A' part of it into a new variable of the parameter type (`A`) - this is known as ***[object slicing](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ObjectSlicing)***. The parameter will no longer 'be-a' `B` instance, so it will behave as an `A` instance, alright.

No need to override virFun in class B, since it uses the argument obj in both cases

In fact, virFun could be a static function. The name is confusing since it isn't even a virFun (virtual function) - it is a regular function that *uses* a virtual function.

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A     { virtual     void sayHello() { cout << "hello from A" << endl; } };
struct B : A { /*virtual*/ void sayHello() { cout << "hello from B" << endl; } };

static void virFun(A& obj)
{
    obj.sayHello();
}

int main()
{
    A a1;
    B b1;

    virFun(a1);
    virFun(b1);
}
```

See it live on http://liveworkspace.org/code/1624496ced29eb4683f5b19072f72f60

```
hello from A
hello from B
```

Comment: Why does it work on reference and not value? Whether reference or pointer or value, they should have same vtable and hence resolve to correct function?

Comment: @Jimm I just added an explanation with a link to more information. Also, which book? See [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for good suggestions

Comment: +1 for adding a link to http://liveworkspace.org. I have been searching for such a site for c++, but only found sites that supported dynamic languages. Ty!!

Answer (score 6):

```
void virFun(A obj);
```

For virtual functions to work you need to pass objects by reference or by pointer to ensure that you're always working with the original object.

```
void virFun(const A &obj);
void virFun(const A *obj);
```

Otherwise `virFun()` will receive a *copy* of your object, which ends up ["slicing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c) it and losing the derived class's information. The copy has `A`'s vtable and is missing `B`'s extra fields. This is usually a disaster.

As a general rule, pass objects around using `T&` or `const T&` rather than plain `T`. Aside from the slicing problem, it's also more efficient.

Comment: I found this answer is very informative than accepted answer, take an upvote :)